# Unwrap "freeform" mesh for laser cutting approximation?

Tags: uv

I'm new to Blender.

I have a geometry which has a very slight double curvature.  I want to 3d print a surface and have a layer of thin laser cut material that sits on top of it (an example of laser cutting surface with holes attached).

The reasons for the holes is that solid parts have to pass through them. The hole locations don't have to line up perfectly, and I included a bit of playroom.

I am trying to find the best way to approximate the geometry in 2D for lazer cutting. Would this be by UV unwrapping? Emphasis on approximation since I guess it's doubly-curved

[image]